# Amazon add-to-cart url parameters

Tags: parameters, hyperlink, amazon-product-api

Ok so Im already an affiliate of amazon.  I'm dynamically generating links based on results from their API.  Im trying to put the customer in front of a permission to add an item to their cart.  I have this structure as an example:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=your-tag-here-20&ASIN.1=B003IXYJYO&Quantity.1=2&ASIN.2=B0002KR8J4&Quantity.2=1&ASIN.3=B0002ZP18E&Quantity.3=1&ASIN.4=B0002ZP3ZA&Quantity.4=2&ASIN.5=B004J2JG6O&Quantity.5=1

This works great as long as Im selling amazon-only products.  What Im trying to do is put them in front of the lowest price for that product (items that are being sold on amazon by other people/dealers).

I already have the lowest prices etc etc.  The problem is structuring the link to get them there.  Do any of you know the parameters in the url that I would add or at least a list of parameters I could sift through to find what Im looking for?

Also, if theres a way to just put the item in their cart as apposed to taking them to a permission to add to cart...that would be that much better!

Thanks in advance!

---

Comment: Im looking for the same thing did you have any luck finding a solution?

Comment: Every product on amazon has its own code e.g. `B003IXYJYO` which is assigned to ASIN.1 in sample url above. Do you want to modify the link manually or you want automatically resolve the above link to the lowest prices link?

Comment: The URL that you have in your question. Is there any way to have this display a mobile version of the site? When on mobile it gives me a desktop page very time.

Answer (score -2):

The "Add to Cart" form enables you to add any number of items to a customer's shopping cart and send the customer to the Amazon retail website for completing the purchase. Some parameters are optional, but you must specify quantity and at least one of the following parameters: ASIN or OfferListingId. AssociateTag is a must for attribution. You can either use this [Online Amazon Add To Cart Link Generator](https://www.techneg.tech/p/amazon-affiliate-add-to-cart-url.html) To Easily Generate Add To Cart Link Without writing attributes by yourself or you can do this manually just like this:

```
"ASIN.1=[ASIN]&Quantity.1=1&ASIN.2=[Another ASIN]&Quantity.2=10"
```

Your final Link May Look Like This:

```
https://www.amazon.in/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AWSAccessKeyId=leNM%2FocHLQ%2ByqCuwtsgoza8buGoeRSlHuoDGRnlb&AssociateTag=ajaykumar9207-21&ASIN.1=B07CQ6Q52H&Quantity.1=1&ASIN.2=B07CQ6Q52H&Quantity.2=1&ASIN.3=B07CQ6Q52H&Quantity.3=1&ASIN.4=B07CQ6Q52H&Quantity.4=1&ASIN.5=B07CQ6Q52H&Quantity.5=1
```